# I want show plain text in the password field and then make it a regular password field on focus in asp.net login page

Tags: asp.net, authentication

please can you send source code

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  Do you actually want "Watermark Text" in the password box before anything is entered?  Or are you trying to make it so that you can see what you are typing?

Comment: Wow, this doesn't have the plzsendtehcodez tag, but it is written in the question itself. Outstanding.

Comment: I amn't able to resolve the problem which is in  user name text box, it should display text[username], and Password text i have to display [ password]. when user enter password text box  it should be display[******].  

I wrote the code, it doesn't displaying password text in the password textbox

asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"  value="password1" onfocus="if(this.value=='password1')this.value='';" 
                    onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='password1';" TextMode="Password"  >password1</asp:TextBox>

Answer (score 5):

Try this.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function ChangeToPassField() {
    document.getElementById('MyPasswordField').type="password";
  }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <input type="text" value="password" id="MyPasswordField" onfocus="ChangeToPassField()" />
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Thanks, But I need user name text box, it should display text[username], and Password text i have to display [ password]. when user enter password text box it should be display[******].

Comment: I thinks this does what you wanted, maybe if you add code to remove the text (`document.getElementById('MyPasswordField').value = "";`)

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot... if you REALLY want to change the field type, which I don't suggest.

Source code examples provided.

http://forums.asp.net/p/1200466/2124486.aspx#2124486

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad idea. You should not be showing users passwords on screen. Ideally, your application should not be able to retrieve passwords, only check a hashed password against a persisted salted hash.

Comment: which is in user name text box, it should display text[username], and Password text i have to display [ password]. when user enter password text box it should be display[******].